# The defined variable won't show up in window object

Tags: javascript

I wrote a javascript code like this:

```
var var1 = 1;
window.var2 = 2;
```

Now on the chrome console, I typed `window` and looked through it, but I cannot find the first variable and only the second one showed up. I suppose both of these variables should exist on global window object.
Can someone clarify why is this?

Comment: And you didn't notice the console error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`??

Comment: `var window.var2 = 2;`.  -----> `window.var2 = 2;`

Comment: And now it's working just fine after your last edit

Comment: The characters after `var ` (i.e. "window.var2") are interpreted as an identifier, you can't have dots in an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Both variables are visible in the windows object:

```js
var var1 = 1;
window.var2 = 2;
console.log(Object.keys(window).filter(k=>k.substr(0,3)=='var'));
```

This will produce:

```
[
  "var1",
  "var2"
]
```

Comment: In my case, it's not. Is it possible it pertain to my Chrome settings?

Comment: This is what my console returns when the 3rd line added: (2) ["ondeviceorientationabsolute", "var2"]

Comment: But what is the result you see from my snippet above (inside the SO snippet window)?

Comment: Clicking on `Run Snippet Code` above on your answer, I see both variables. Yet on my local machine, I see just the second variable.

Comment: Also, same issue on Firefox. Just seeing the variables defined explicitly on `window` object.

Comment: Are you sure that the key *really* does not exist anywhere? I modified my snippet above to specifically look for anything starting with "var". Maybe you can try that on your browsers again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was due the fact that I put `type="module"` attribute inside `script` tag. Removing that, I am able to see it on global window object.

```
<script type="module" src="js/app.js"></script>
```